# What is causing my logger to "reconfig" the properties every minute? Blitz4j.

Tags: logging, netflix

I am currently trying out the Blitz4j by netflix. Everything seems to work fine but for some reason I see in the log files that log4j is constantly trying to configure the properties(every minute).

Below is my config for log4j:

```
# logging properties
## root logger options
log4j.rootCategory=OFF
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, LOGTXT
## stdout, logs show on console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=com.netflix.logging.log4jAdapter.NFPatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} %5p [ %c ] %m%n
## LOGTXT, logs to a file
log4j.appender.LOGTXT=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGTXT.File=./log/log.txt
log4j.appender.LOGTXT.Append=true
log4j.appender.LOGTXT.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.LOGTXT.DatePattern='-' yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.LOGTXT.layout=com.netflix.logging.log4jAdapter.NFPatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGTXT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} %5p [ %c ] %m%n
log4j.logger.com.otcmarkets.mfa.common.util.logging.MfaLogFactory=INFO, stdout, LOGTXT
```

In the console/stdout, every minute I see this:

```
2013-04-12 06:36:36  INFO [ com.netflix.blitz4j.LoggingConfiguration ] Configuring log4j dynamically
2013-04-12 06:36:36  INFO [ com.netflix.blitz4j.LoggingConfiguration ] Updated properties is :{log4j.logger.com.otcmarkets.mfa.common.util.logging.MfaLogFactory=INFO, stdout, LOGTXT}
2013-04-12 06:36:36  INFO [ com.netflix.blitz4j.LoggingConfiguration ] The root category for log4j.rootCategory now is OFF
2013-04-12 06:36:36  INFO [ com.netflix.blitz4j.LoggingConfiguration ] The root category for log4j.rootLogger now is INFO, stdout, LOGTXT
2013-04-12 06:36:36  INFO [ com.netflix.blitz4j.LoggingConfiguration ] Configuring log4j with properties :{log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender, log4j.appender.LOGTXT.Append=true, log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, LOGTXT, log4j.appender.LOGTXT.File=./log/log.txt, log4j.appender.LOGTXT=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender, log4j.appender.LOGTXT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} %5p [ %c ] %m%n, log4j.appender.LOGTXT.layout=com.netflix.logging.log4jAdapter.NFPatternLayout, log4j.appender.LOGTXT.Threshold=DEBUG, log4j.loggerFactory=com.netflix.blitz4j.NFCategoryFactory, log4j.logger.com.otcmarkets.mfa.common.util.logging.MfaLogFactory=INFO, stdout, LOGTXT, log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} %5p [ %c ] %m%n, log4j.appender.LOGTXT.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd, log4j.appender.stdout.layout=com.netflix.logging.log4jAdapter.NFPatternLayout, log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out, log4j.rootCategory=OFF}
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[INFO, stdout, LOGTXT].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category root set to INFO
log4j: Parsing appender named "stdout".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} %5p [ %c ] %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [target] to [System.out].
log4j: Parsed "stdout" options.
log4j: Parsing appender named "LOGTXT".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "LOGTXT".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} %5p [ %c ] %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "LOGTXT".
log4j: Setting property [append] to [true].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [./log/log.txt].
log4j: Setting property [threshold] to [DEBUG].
log4j: Setting property [datePattern] to ['.' yyyy-MM-dd].
log4j: setFile called: ./log/log.txt, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Appender [LOGTXT] to be rolled at midnight.
log4j: Parsed "LOGTXT" options.
log4j: Setting category factory to [com.netflix.blitz4j.NFCategoryFactory].
log4j: Parsing for [com.otcmarkets.mfa.common.util.logging.MfaLogFactory] with value=[INFO, stdout, LOGTXT].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category com.otcmarkets.mfa.common.util.logging.MfaLogFactory set to INFO
log4j: Parsing appender named "stdout".
log4j: Appender "stdout" was already parsed.
log4j: Parsing appender named "LOGTXT".
log4j: Appender "LOGTXT" was already parsed.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.com.otcmarkets.mfa.common.util.logging.MfaLogFactory=[null]
log4j: Finished configuring.
```

In the log.txt file, every minute I see this:

```
2013-04-12 06:38:36  INFO [ com.netflix.blitz4j.LoggingConfiguration ] Configuring log4j dynamically
2013-04-12 06:38:36  INFO [ com.netflix.blitz4j.LoggingConfiguration ] Updated properties is :{log4j.logger.com.otcmarkets.mfa.common.util.logging.MfaLogFactory=INFO, stdout, LOGTXT}
2013-04-12 06:38:36  INFO [ com.netflix.blitz4j.LoggingConfiguration ] The root category for log4j.rootCategory now is OFF
2013-04-12 06:38:36  INFO [ com.netflix.blitz4j.LoggingConfiguration ] The root category for log4j.rootLogger now is INFO, stdout, LOGTXT
2013-04-12 06:38:36  INFO [ com.netflix.blitz4j.LoggingConfiguration ] Configuring log4j with properties :{log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender, log4j.appender.LOGTXT.Append=true, log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, LOGTXT, log4j.appender.LOGTXT.File=./log/log.txt, log4j.appender.LOGTXT=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender, log4j.appender.LOGTXT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} %5p [ %c ] %m%n, log4j.appender.LOGTXT.layout=com.netflix.logging.log4jAdapter.NFPatternLayout, log4j.appender.LOGTXT.Threshold=DEBUG, log4j.loggerFactory=com.netflix.blitz4j.NFCategoryFactory, log4j.logger.com.otcmarkets.mfa.common.util.logging.MfaLogFactory=INFO, stdout, LOGTXT, log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} %5p [ %c ] %m%n, log4j.appender.LOGTXT.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd, log4j.appender.stdout.layout=com.netflix.logging.log4jAdapter.NFPatternLayout, log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out, log4j.rootCategory=OFF}
2013-04-12 06:38:36  INFO [ com.netflix.blitz4j.LoggingConfiguration ] Configuring log4j dynamically
2013-04-12 06:38:36  INFO [ com.netflix.blitz4j.LoggingConfiguration ] Updated properties is :{log4j.logger.com.otcmarkets.mfa.common.util.logging.MfaLogFactory=INFO, stdout, LOGTXT}
2013-04-12 06:38:36  INFO [ com.netflix.blitz4j.LoggingConfiguration ] The root category for log4j.rootCategory now is OFF
2013-04-12 06:38:36  INFO [ com.netflix.blitz4j.LoggingConfiguration ] The root category for log4j.rootLogger now is INFO, stdout, LOGTXT
2013-04-12 06:38:36  INFO [ com.netflix.blitz4j.LoggingConfiguration ] Configuring log4j with properties :{log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender, log4j.appender.LOGTXT.Append=true, log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, LOGTXT, log4j.appender.LOGTXT.File=./log/log.txt, log4j.appender.LOGTXT=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender, log4j.appender.LOGTXT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} %5p [ %c ] %m%n, log4j.appender.LOGTXT.layout=com.netflix.logging.log4jAdapter.NFPatternLayout, log4j.appender.LOGTXT.Threshold=DEBUG, log4j.loggerFactory=com.netflix.blitz4j.NFCategoryFactory, log4j.logger.com.otcmarkets.mfa.common.util.logging.MfaLogFactory=INFO, stdout, LOGTXT, log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} %5p [ %c ] %m%n, log4j.appender.LOGTXT.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd, log4j.appender.stdout.layout=com.netflix.logging.log4jAdapter.NFPatternLayout, log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out, log4j.rootCategory=OFF}
```

Somehow in the file, it logs the configuration stuff twice.

Here is my "log factory":

```
public class MyLogFactory {
    // init the logging configuration instance
    private final static LoggingConfiguration logConfig = LoggingConfiguration.getInstance();

    static {
        /*  set up the properties for logging
            we will use two forms of logging
                1. stdout
                2. log file, rollover is every midnight
        */
        Properties props = new Properties();
        System.out.println("configuring properties for log4j");
        // root logger options
        props.setProperty("log4j.rootCategory", "OFF");
        props.setProperty("log4j.rootLogger", "INFO, stdout, LOGTXT");
        // direct log messages to stdout
        props.setProperty("log4j.appender.stdout", "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender");
        props.setProperty("log4j.appender.stdout.Target", "System.out");
        props.setProperty("log4j.appender.stdout.layout", "com.netflix.logging.log4jAdapter.NFPatternLayout");
        props.setProperty("log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern", "%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} %5p [ %c ] %m%n");
        // direct log messages to log file
        props.setProperty("log4j.appender.LOGTXT", "org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender");
        props.setProperty("log4j.appender.LOGTXT.File", "./log/log.txt");
        props.setProperty("log4j.appender.LOGTXT.Append", "true");
        props.setProperty("log4j.appender.LOGTXT.Threshold", "DEBUG");
        props.setProperty("log4j.appender.LOGTXT.DatePattern", "'.' yyyy-MM-dd");
        props.setProperty("log4j.appender.LOGTXT.layout", "com.netflix.logging.log4jAdapter.NFPatternLayout");
        props.setProperty("log4j.appender.LOGTXT.layout.ConversionPattern", "%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} %5p [ %c ] %m%n");
        props.setProperty("log4j.logger.com.otcmarkets.mfa.common.util.logging.MfaLogFactory", "INFO,stdout,LOGTXT");

        logConfig.configure(props);
        System.out.println("finished configuring properties for log4j");
    }

    public static Logger getLogger(Class clazz)
    {
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the default behavior of Archaius (which is used under the hood by blitz4j). Basically, there is an issue where Archaius is detecting every time it polls (every minute, by default) that the property defining a logger has changed, regardless of whether or not the property has actually changed.

So, in your case, Archaius is detecting every minute that the log4j.logger.com.otcmarkets.mfa.common.util.logging.MfaLogFactory property has changed, and then it triggers a reconfigure of log4j via blitz4j.

See the following issue on Archaius' github for more info: [Github issue](https://github.com/Netflix/archaius/issues/101)